# VS Code: Why does the explorer panel disappear when I go into search?

Tags: visual-studio-code

When I click search in the sidebar tab, the explorer tab disappears. I haven't been able to figure out why this is happening. There doesn't seem to be a setting for it and users I've spoken to don't experience this behaviour. See demo below:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/FbTJK.jpg

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I found out what was wrong - explorer was unchecked in the 'activity bar' context menu. You can change which panels are checked by right clicking on the sidebar.

[image: menu]